# Shake window in Ursina

Tags: window, shake, ursina

Is there a way to shake the ursina game window. like "window.shake(duration = 1)" doesn't work.

if there isn't, could it be possible to make all the entity's inside the game shake at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Shake the window or the camera? There's `camera.shake()` which will do screenshake.